# Двойное двоеточие (::) Почему это так вычисляется?

Tags: php, static

Почему $c вычислится в 2?
Что происходит?

Мы создаём класс Альфа, затем создаём Бета, который её наследует.
Альфа задаёт статичное свойство.
Здесь $a - инкрементирует $valA, т.к. через перезагрузку мы обращаемся к родителю - Альфе. $b - инкрементирует $valB, т.к. мы обращаемся к свойству класса. $c - тоже обращается к родителю, но почему то вычисляется в 2. $d - равнозначно случаю с $b. 
Где ошибка в ходе мыслей и как работает на самом деле?

```
class Alfa {
    public static $valA = 0;
}

class Beta extends Alfa {
    public $valB = 0;
}

$beta1 = new Beta();

$a = ++$beta1::$valA;
$b = ++$beta1->valB;

$beta2 = new Beta();

$c = ++$beta2::$valA;
$d = ++$beta2->valB;
```

Comment: В том то и дело, по моему разумению не должны, но сохраняются.
Если в первом объекте всё вычисляется в единицы, то и во втором так должно происходить. А происходит нечто другое. $c вычисляется в двойку. Почему не 1?

Comment: а да все верно, там же `++` стоит, попробуйте поменять на `$a = $beta1::$valA + 1;`, по факту сейчас он переписывает таким образом значение в классе

Comment: почему переписывает? из кода это не следует,
или я ошибаюсь? в каком моменте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Статическое свойство класса одно для всех объектов данного класса и его потомков(если не было принудительно переопределено). Можно считать его глобальным состоянием в области видимости класса.

```
class A{
    public static $a = 1;
}
class B extends A{};

class C extends A{
        public static $a = 100;
};

$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$c = new C();

printf('         %7s%7s%7s'.PHP_EOL, 'A::$a', 'B::$a', 'C::$a');
printf('initial  %7d%7d%7d'.PHP_EOL, A::$a, B::$a, C::$a);
$a::$a++;
printf('$a::$a++ %7d%7d%7d'.PHP_EOL, A::$a, B::$a, C::$a);
$b::$a++;
printf('$b::$a++ %7d%7d%7d'.PHP_EOL, A::$a, B::$a, C::$a);
$c::$a++;
printf('$c::$a++ %7d%7d%7d'.PHP_EOL, A::$a, B::$a, C::$a);
```

Вывод

```
           A::$a  B::$a  C::$a
initial        1      1    100
$a::$a++       2      2    100
$b::$a++       3      3    100
$c::$a++       3      3    101
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/95f31ed26cc0d0a2da5b61effe37fa3cd876977d)

Answer (score 2):

Попробую дать ответ на этот вопрос, **таким образом как я это понимаю.**

Когда мы создаем класс `Alfa`, мы объявляем статическое свойство `$valA`. Иными словами, это означает что свойство принадлежит именно классу `Alfa`, но никак не объекту класса `Alfa`. Мы ведь не можем обратится к этому свойству следующим образом `$beta->valA.

Cоответственно, каждый раз инрементируя свойство `$valA` мы инкрементируем статическое свойство класса, но никак не свойство созданного нами нового объекта